# how to set the last list item visible in android while scrolling?

Tags: android

My EndlessScrollListener.java code is:

```
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;

public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
protected int visibleThreshold = 12;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;

public EndlessScrollListener() {
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
    this.currentPage = startPage;
}


public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) {

    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount)
    {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0)
        { 
            this.loading = true;
            } 
    }

    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        currentPage++;
    }

    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // Don't take any action on changed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
scroll.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });
```

scroll is the ScrollView.
But before you post, please search in the stackoverflow or google.com.